# how to use nouveau on opengl

Tags: opengl, nouveau

I am on Ubuntu/20.04 with GM107M (GeForce GTX 960M):

```
    $ sudo lshw -class video
  *-display                 
       description: 3D controller
       product: GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
       vendor: NVIDIA Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       version: a2
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=nouveau latency=0
       resources: irq:136 memory:de000000-deffffff memory:c0000000-cfffffff memory:d0000000-d1ffffff ioport:e000(size=128) memory:df000000-df07ffff
  *-display
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: HD Graphics 530
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 06
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pciexpress msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:135 memory:dd000000-ddffffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:f000(size=64) memory:c0000-dffff
```

I have installed nouveau driver without problem:

```
    $ lspci -k | grep -A 2 -E "(VGA|3D)"
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation HD Graphics 530 (rev 06)
    DeviceName:  Onboard IGD
    Subsystem: Dell HD Graphics 530
--
02:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] (rev a2)
    Subsystem: Dell GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M]
    Kernel driver in use: nouveau
```

However, my confusion lies upon the fact that nothing seems to use the nouveau driver at  all:

```
$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
OpenGL vendor string: Intel
OpenGL renderer string: Mesa Intel(R) HD Graphics 530 (SKL GT2)
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.6 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.1.7 - kisak-mesa PPA
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.6 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 20.1.7 - kisak-mesa PPA
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.60
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
OpenGL ES profile version string: OpenGL ES 3.2 Mesa 20.1.7 - kisak-mesa PPA
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: OpenGL ES GLSL ES 3.20
```

How do I force 3D being rendered by the nvidia card instead of the Intel one?

Thanks in advance

ps. ohh trust me, I tried to use the proprietary nvidia driver...struggled for days, even upgraded my kernel to 5.8.5 without much success.  at least x started when nouveau is installed, thus I will stick  with nouveau for now.

Comment: Research "hybrid graphics" - that's what your device has and understanding that setup will clue you in on the challenge that you face

Comment: First, nouveau is not very useful for 3D, second, it doesn't have support for Nvidia's hybrid stuff, which is proprietary. Perhaps we can help you solve whatever problems with Nvidia driver, it usually works well, but go back to the default Ubuntu kernel. PS: Why trust you?